# How I can create a new repository and upload it to github

Tags: git, github

I don't know like to create a new repository.

I need to finish a project but I don't understand anything about the repository creation step.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pre-existing codebase on your machine (which I assume is the case), and you need to "upload" this codebase to GitHub, then you would need to perform a few actions:

1. Create a new repo on GitHub. If you are not familiar with the command line, I suggest doing it on the Web UI. You should follow the link in @Ben's answer: [Create a repo on GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/create-a-repo)
2. Initialize a local repo on your machine. To do this, you should fire up a terminal and `cd` into the folder of your codebase.

   ```
   cd /path/to/your/code
   git init
   ```
3. Link up your local repo with the remote repo on GitHub.
   Go to your newly created repo, copy the link as shown in the picture below:

   [image: Repo url]

   Ensure you are copying the `https` URL. The `ssh` type URL requires a little bit more configurations, and you can do this when you are more comfortable with working with `git` and `ssh` tooling.

   Then run the following command:

   ```
   git remote add origin <your repo url>
   ```

   You can [read more about git repo, remote repo and local repo here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-a-git-repository/)
4. Commit and push your code.

   ```
   git commit -a -m "initial commit"
   git push origin main
   # you will be required to enter your username and password
   ```

   GitHub requires you to use a Personal Access Token if you are pushing your code in the command line. You can refer to [this link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to create a PAT for yourself.

The next step for you should be learning more about the `git` tooling. I would recommend reading [Atlassian's git tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control), or [the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)

Comment: All those steps are done automatically by the local command `gh repo create` I detail in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72844016/6309).

Answer (score 0):

If you new repository is one you want to create locally *and* on Github, you can do so easily with the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli).

Once [installed](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation=), authenticate yourself with [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login), then create your new repository with [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)

If you don't have a repository yet:

```bash
# create a new remote repository and clone it locally
gh repo create my-project --public --clone
```

If you already have a repository locally:

```bash
# create a remote repository from the current directory
cd /path/to/my/local/repository
gh repo create my-project --private --source=. --remote=upstream
git push -u main
```

Use `--public` or `--private` depending on the visibility you want to associate to the new GitHub repository.